# VBA: returning a range from a function issue

Tags: function, vba, parameters

I am trying to clean up my code and there is a snippet which I use to find the last cell. This is used for multiple worksheets. When i turn this into a function it appears to cause an error. I believe its the way I return the range which appears to be the issue. I get a run time error of "Object  Required"  In the code below I am trying to create a pivot table by capturing all non blanks cells from a different table. If anyone has suggestions where I am going wrong it would be much appreciated?

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim cacheOfPt As PivotCache 'this is the source data for the pt
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem 'pivot item are the values of a particular pivot feld
Dim myRange As Range
Dim wsPivot As Worksheet
Dim wsJournal As Worksheet

Set wsJournal = Worksheets("Sales_Journals")
Set myRange = myRangeFunc(wsJournal)

Worksheets.Add.Name = "UA.01.01 Breakdown per Product"
wsJournal.Select
Set cacheOfPt = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, myRange.Address(0, 0))'<= this line is the issue
```

function for last cell

```
Function myRangeFunc(ws As Worksheet) As Range


        On Error Resume Next
        With ws
            Set LastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            Set lastCol = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
        End With

        If Not LastRow Is Nothing Then
            Set myRangeFunc = Range([A1], Cells(LastRow.Row, lastCol.Column))
            Debug.Print "Range is " & myRangeFunc.Address(0, 0)
        Else
            MsgBox "sheet is blank", vbCritical
        End If

End Function
```

Comment: `LastCol` is never defined, it should be `Set myRangeFunc = Range([A1], Cells(LastRow.Row, LastRow.Column))`

Comment: You are right, however I get an error now of Object requried still asscoiated with the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cells` method returns a range object, the default property of which is its `.Value`, so when you do this:

```
Set myRangeFunc = Range([A1], Cells(LastRow.Row, lastCol.Column))
```

You are actually doing this:

```
Set myRangeFunc = Range([A1], Cells(LastRow.Row, lastCol.Column).Value)
```

Which will **always fail** (unless that cell contains a valid address string, like "$A$1", etc.).

Do this instead:

```
Set myRangeFunc = Range([A1].Address, Cells(LastRow.Row, lastCol.Column).Address)
```

Re the 424 error, I would expect that if either of the `LastRow` or `LastCol` are `Nothing` (i.e., there is no data found).

Clean up the function a bit and properly declare your variables and **get rid of On Error Resume Next**:

```
Function myRangeFunc(ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim LastRow as Range, LastCol as Range
    Dim r as Long, c as Long

        With ws
            Set LastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            Set lastCol = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
            If LastRow Is Nothing Then
                r = 1
            Else: r = LastRow.Row
            End If
            If LastCol Is Nothing Then
                c = 1
            Else: c = LastCol.Column
            End If

        End With


        Set myRangeFunc = Range("A1", Cells(r, c).Address)

        If LastRow Is Nothing And LastCol Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Sheet is blank!"

End Function
```

Comment: Hmm it appears to work on every second attempt. Object required error message

Comment: I would expect that error if either `LastRow` *or* `LastColumn` (or both) evaluate to `Nothing`.

Comment: see revised answer which I think should fix that.